# Prove this integral limitation

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

I considered this problem.

$I_{n}$ is defined as follows
$$I_{n}=\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{e^x \, |\sin x \, \sin nx \, \sin 2nx|}{\left(\frac{2x}{\pi}\right)^n + 1} \, dx$$
You can use these inequalities
$$2.71<e<2.72, \quad \text{and} \quad 3.14<\pi<3.15$$
to prove this limiting case
$$\frac{6}{5}<{\lim_{n \to \infty} I_{n}}<\frac{5}{4}.$$

However, I cannot solve this.

I considered when the variable $n$ is a very large number.

Here is the shape of the graph at that time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJFeR.png

I thought about trapezoidal area evaluation and tangent area evaluation.
However, the graph shape is too vague, I could not do that.
If you have an answer, could you tell me hints? I'm sorry my broken English,I'm Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$ J_n = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^x \left| \sin x \sin(nx) \sin(2nx) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Then

$$ \left| I_n - J_n \right| \leq \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{2x}{\pi}\right)^n e^x \, \mathrm{d}x \to 0, $$

hence it suffices to evaluate the limit of $(J_n)$ as $n\to\infty$. To this end, we invoke:

> **Lemma.** Let $f, g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be continuous. Also, assume that $g$ is $T$-periodic. Then for any $a < b$,
>
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x = \overline{g} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x, $$
>
> where $\overline{g} = \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is the average value of $g$.

From this, it follows that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} J_n
&= \biggl( \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^x \sin x \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr) \biggl( \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \left| \sin x \sin (2x) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr) \\
&= \frac{e^{\pi/2} + 1}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{3 \pi} \\
&= \frac{2(e^{\pi/2} + 1)}{3 \pi}
\approx 1.23302,
\end{align*}

which lies between $\frac{6}{5} = 1.2$ and $\frac{5}{4} = 1.25$.

Comment: Nice. Some years ago, I learned this lemma in this statement: If $f, g$ are Riemann integrable on $[0, T]$ and $g$ is period with period $T$.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^T f(x)g(nx) \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(x)\mathrm{d} x \int_0^T g(x)\mathrm{d}x.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Some thoughts.**

For the upper bound:

**Fact 1.** It holds that $\mathrm{e}^x \sin x \le \frac{975}{736} x^2 + x$ on $[0, \pi/2]$.
(The proof is omitted here.)

Let
$$J_n := \int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \left(\frac{975}{736} x^2 + x\right) \, |\sin nx \, \sin 2nx| \, \mathrm{d} x.$$
We have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} J_n = \frac{325}{4416}\pi^2 + \frac16 \pi. \tag{1}$$
(The proof of (1) is given at the end.)

By Fact 1, we have $I_n \le J_n$ for all $n$.
Thus, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n \le \lim_{n\to \infty} J_n = \frac{325}{4416}\pi^2 + \frac16 \pi < \frac54.$$

---

*Proof of (1).*

$J_n$ admits a simple closed form.

We deal with odd $n$. The case of even $n$ is similar.

By the substition $x = y/n$, we have
\begin{align*}
 J_n &= \int_{0}^\frac{n\pi}{2} \left(\frac{975}{736} \frac{y^2}{n^2} + \frac{y}{n}\right) \, |\sin y \, \sin 2y| \cdot \frac{1}{n}\, \mathrm{d} y\\[6pt]
 &= \int_{0}^\frac{n\pi}{2} \left(\frac{975}{736} \frac{y^2}{n^2} + \frac{y}{n}\right) \cdot 2\sin^2 y \cdot |\cos y| \cdot \frac{1}{n}\, \mathrm{d} y \\[6pt]
 &= \int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \left(\frac{975}{736} \frac{y^2}{n^2} + \frac{y}{n}\right) \cdot 2\sin^2 y \cdot |\cos y| \cdot \frac{1}{n}\, \mathrm{d} y\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \sum_{k=0}^{(n-3)/2} \int_{(2k+1)\pi/2}^{(2k+3)\pi/2} \left(\frac{975}{736} \frac{y^2}{n^2} + \frac{y}{n}\right) \cdot 2\sin^2 y \cdot |\cos y| \cdot \frac{1}{n}\, \mathrm{d} y\\[6pt]
 &= \int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \left(\frac{975}{736} \frac{y^2}{n^2} + \frac{y}{n}\right) \cdot 2\sin^2 y \cdot \cos y \cdot \frac{1}{n}\, \mathrm{d} y\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \sum_{k=0}^{(n-3)/2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \left(\frac{975}{736} \frac{[(2k+1)\pi/2 + z]^2}{n^2} + \frac{(2k+1)\pi/2 + z}{n}\right)\\[6pt] &\qquad\qquad \cdot 2\cos^2 z \cdot \sin z \cdot \frac{1}{n}\, \mathrm{d} z \\[6pt]
 &= \left(\frac{2925\pi^2 - 18200}{13248n^3} + \frac{3\pi - 4}{9n^2}\right) \\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \left(\frac{325}{4416}\pi^2 + \frac16\pi + \frac{-2925\pi^2 + 18200}{13248 n^3}
 + \frac{975\pi^2 - 1104\pi - 9100}{6624n^2}\right)\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{325}{4416}\pi^2 + \frac16\pi
 + \frac{975\pi^2 - 1104\pi - 9100}{6624n^2}.
\end{align*}
(*Note*: I used *Maple*. )